# How can I get the innerhtml text of a element with a specific class?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get on the console the text of a specific element. If I check the document element by class:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("QN1ves1hk0MUeUx70asdhg7VPFdkXeNa oPikK3G2Tkv7yYgW_phm8QoqS9GeopSy");
```

I get this:

[image: console print]

I want the text "Your request was successfully submitted." as a return.

This how the element looks like in the inspector:

[image: element inspection]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that can be iterated and accessed like an array. If you want to return the `.innerHTML` of the first element, then you can just do this:

```js
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
console.log(collection[0].innerHTML)
```

```html
<span class="example">Text</span>
```

However, multiple elements may have the same class name, so if you want to print the `.innerHTML` of all elements with the class, you can use a for-loop:

```js
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
for (const el of collection) {
  console.log(el.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<span class="example">Text 1</span>
<span class="example">Text 2</span>
<span class="example">Text 3</span>
```